# variable or field 'name of var' declared void

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, header-files

When I compile this program i get error: variable or field 'push green; declared void. I have 2 files: a header file and a cpp file. Not sure of what is causing this error.

```
/////thinker.h
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>

class thinking_cap
 {
   public:
      void slots(char new_green[], char new_red[]);
      void push_green() const;
      void push_red() const;

 private:
 char green_string[50];
 char red_string[50];
};



////////  thinker.cpp
  #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "thinker.h"

 int main( ) 
  {
    thinking_cap student;
    thinking_cap fan;
    student.slots( "Hello",  "Goodbye");
    fan.slots( "Go Cougars!", "Boo!");
    student.push_green( );
    fan.push_green( );
   student.push_red( );
   return 0;
 }

 void thinking_cap::slots(char new_green[ ], char new_red[ ])
 {
   assert(strlen(new_green) < 50);
   assert(strlen(new_red) < 50);
   strcpy(green_string,  new_green);
   strcpy(red_string, new_red);
 }
void thinking_cap::push_green 
 {
   cout << green_string << endl;
 }
 void thinking_cap::push_red 
 {
   cout << red_string << endl;
 }
```

Comment: When you *compile* this program you get a compilation error, and you haven't quoted it accurately: at least it isn't clear where the error ends and your own words resume.

Answer (score 0):

Down the bottom you're missing some parentheses.  Try this:

```
void thinking_cap::push_green() const
{
    cout << green_string << endl;
}
void thinking_cap::push_red () const
{
    cout << red_string << endl;
}
```